# Accept server only GET request

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, .htaccess, get

I'm making an GET request to my server with AJAX+JS. I'm using it to delete file like this:

```
delete.php?file_id=0123456789&user=555555
```

When I send GET request delete.php will delte file with ID 0123456789, but is there a way to accept only request that server makes to itself.

For example if user opens new tab and types `www.mysite.com/delete.php?file_id=0123456789` server will decline that request, but if I call it with JS function server will accept the request.

Comment: Using `GET` for requests is HIGHLY exploitable. What if I hacked a 1x1 pixel image request into your page that would pass a file name? You'd never notice you just sent a request to delete something...

Comment: The AJAX request comes from the browser (client side) and not from the server itself.

Comment: POST is insecure, too. You should add some kind of authentication and each user should only be allowed to delete his own stuff.

Comment: JS is clientside, every solution you have using JS can be emulated by a user who wants to do something illegal. Do a check if the current user is allowed to delete a file on server-side.

Comment: You need to determine whether a user is authorized to delete a file.

Comment: Thanks, I'll add some kind of token with POST, also user_id is required to delte file

Answer (score 0):

How about using X-XSRF-TOKEN
in combination with Angular JS?

This will require your webapplication to generate and check this token, but your AJAX request will be authenticated.